how to add text after pattern match
How to to add parameter extension server=”I am a teapot" after <Connector and Before Port=... with sed ?
before the addition:
<Connector Port=8080

after the addition:
<Connector server=”I am a teapot" Port=8080


Can any of the match string be variable, eg should this match server="something else"?

Is this XML? I suggest to use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Please show what you tried, what results you obtained and how it was wrong.

A simple substitution form of sed using two capture groups (...) to capture text before and after the space and then inserting your new text between two backrefernces (e.g. \1 and \2) will do, e.g.
sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]])(.*$)/\1server="I am a teapot" \2/'

Expanation

Normal sed substitution form sed -E 's/find/replace/' using -E extended regular expressions  where find is:
^ anchor to beginning of line,
( begin capture gruop,
[^[:space:]] match all characters that are not a [:space:] (whitespace),
+ with repetition of 1 or more characters,
[[:space:]] followed by a space,
) end the first capture group,
( began second capture group,
.*$ matching all characters through end of line,
) end second capture group, followed by the replace which is
\1 reinsert all text matched in first capture group using first numbered backreference,
server="I am a teapot" insert your text followed by a space, and finally,
\2 reinsert all text matched in the second capture group.

Example Use/Output
You can simply pipe the information to sed to see it work,
echo "<Connector Port=8080" | sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]])(.*$)/\1server="I am a teapot" \2/'
<Connector server="I am a teapot" Port=8080

If your sed doesn't support -E (ERE - extended regex), you can do the same with basic regex (BRE) as well. (you just need to escape the parenthesis and replace + with *)  Let me know if you have further questions.
note: if you are absolutely sure your line will always begin with <Connection followed by a single space, you can simply replace the space, e.g. sed 's/[[:space:]]/ server="I am a teapot" /', but that falls apart if you have a leading or space within the initial text. Either way, if your format changes, you will need to adapt the regex.
note Example
echo "<Connector Port=8080" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/ server="I am a teapot" /'
<Connector server="I am a teapot" Port=8080


sorry there is a mistake. I have tried it and it doesn't work. This is the result :
server="I am a teapot"  
server="I am a teapot"  

@middlewaretechnology that means the example in your question doesn't adequately represent your real input. Please fix your example to be more truly representative of your real input and add the expected output.

@middlewaretechnology - I'm still unclear what all can be contained in server="i am a teapot". In your example you show that as being the only addition and provide only a single line. If the line in your example is part of a bigger file, and if server="i am a teapot" can vary in form from what you have provided, then yes, of course, the expression will need to be adjusted. If you can provide a representative example, then I'm happy to help further. You will find both examples above correctly modify the text you have provided as you indicated was required.

If you are keying by port, then you can add a match to the beginning to only match on 8080, etc. with the form sed '/match/s/find/replace/', where match would be 8080$.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's/<Connector /&server="I am a teapot" /' file

Replace the match by itself and the intended string (not forgetting the additional space at the end).
If Port=8080 must also match, use:
sed -E 's/(<Connector.*)(Port=8080)/\1server="I am a teapot" \2/' file

In this case, create two back references of both match strings and sandwich the required string between them.
If it is just a word between two words:
sed 's/ / server="I am a teapot" /' file

